# Stylelint invalid option [WebStorm 2021.2] error

Tags: webstorm, stylelint

WebStorm 2021.2 does not process SCSS files, in sass files Stylelint works fine. How can I directly tell WebStorm which file extensions to use?

**package.json**

[image: package.json]

**Stylelint config**

[image: config]

**The error:**

[image]

**WebStorm settings:**

[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53225/Stylelint-Plugin-is-Incompatible-with-Stylelint-v14-SCSS is fixed in 2021.2.4, did you try updating the IDE?

Comment: But I would like to use this version) I saw this problem on youtrack just thought maybe there is a way to fix it

Comment: So you have `2021.2` version. What problems do you have with updating to the MINOR `2021.2.4` version? I see none at all.

Comment: I have WebStorm 2023.3.4, and experience seemingly the same issue with stylelint 16.2.1: "Stylelint: invalid option ." says the IDE, while stylelint process itself works fine.